# Blind vias pitfalls when hand soldering parts

Tags: soldering, via

I'm going to use blind and buried vias in an upcoming project for the first time.

As with all boards, there is a high chance of hand soldering for the first revision, and since the vias will be much smaller then the ones we've used previously, I wanted to know what are the pitfalls when doing hand soldering near there vias?

Are they more susceptible to collapse? Should we use lower temperature on the solder iron, different flux/solder paste?
Basically any advice will be welcome :)

Comment: Never had any issues with vias in a professional manufactured board (even when hand soldering, and I'm not the best there)

Answer (score 1):

If your blank circuit boards with blind and buried vias are built by a manufacturer that has a good reputation and a proven track record of quality then the boards should be able to survive any soldering because the vias themselves are plated through with copper. This plating is not going to melt away at the temperatures where soldering is done.

I do have to question some things though. If you are using blind and buried vias it suggests that you are trying to fabricate a board with very high density parts and many small components. The typical usage would have BGA chips and other direct attach bump die IC devices. These parts are typically not hand solderable. The bare circuit boards themselves would be many layer boards and rather expensive. The equation just does not add up to where the use of hand soldered prototype first boards makes any sense.

You should be planning to take your boards to one of the low volume friendly fabrication shops that can prepare the assembly of your first boards for you. The overall cost delta to your project is well worth it and possibly even mandatory anyway. There are shops that will do this type of build for you and are able to take components on cut tape and work without a solder paste mask!!

If your first article boards are really aimed at development and technical proof of concept then it would make sense to build out your circuits on larger boards without blind and buried vias using technology that is less dense and cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. The board will arrive assembled (and without BGA parts)
As I have very little experience with non-standard vias, I was mainly trying to get a feel for the inevitable process of reworks once it doesn't work well...